# Vault throwing 403 using AppRole authentication in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a spring boot application that authenticates with vault using approle+bound_cidr_list setup. Authentication is working fine when testing with docker-compose but the same is failing with Kubernetes with a 403 error.

```
2020-07-20 16:38:33.699  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.vault.config.VaultConfigTemplate   : Fetching config from Vault at: database/creds/service-db-role
2020-07-20 16:38:33.980  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.vault.config.VaultConfigTemplate   : Could not locate PropertySource: Status 403 Forbidden [database/creds/service-db-role]: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied

; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

**We have also tested this by installing vault in different VM and application in another VM, and it works fine.**

**If the authentication is happening fine with docker-compose why the same is failing with kubernetes?**

Do I need to configure kubernetes-auth here?

I am stuck at this authentication issue for the last two days, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the same credentials(ie. same policies for that user) in both cases to connect vault server

Comment: yeah you need to configure your k8s service account

Comment: How did deploy vault on you k8s cluster?

Comment: I have used helm chart to install vault and consul.
The problem is resolved now. The issue was with a char missing in vault policy and it caused 403.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? It might help others who encounter same issue.